# How should I check whether uploaded files are secure on a shared webhosting?

Tags: php, file, server, antivirus

I am creating an app that requires the user to upload some image which will be stored in a folder on the server. I have no way of installing clamAV to check if the file is safe, and I would like to use virustotal's API as a last resort.

I am using PHP on a shared webhost.

How can I ensure that the file is secure? or is it even possible?

Comment: Store in a folder above the www folder then nothing should be able to access that folder from t'internet

Comment: I can't create a folder above the www folder unfortunately